# Creating list instead hard coding param values

Tags: java, arrays

I have following code in Java.

```
private final int level1BallCount = 5;
private final int level2BallCount = 10;
private final int level3BallCount = 15;
private final int level4BallCount = 20;
private final int level5BallCount = 25;
private final int level6BallCount = 30;
private final int level7BallCount = 35;
private final int level8BallCount = 40;
private final int level9BallCount = 45;
private final int level10BallCount = 50;
private final int level11BallCount = 55;
private final int level12BallCount = 60;
```

Now it all functions properly, however I would like to know if there is some easier way like lists for this, because when I type getters and setters for this, code goes really huge.

Anyone with a better idea how to do this?

Comment: if its a constant better use a separate file or just create a Enum so that it is easy to maintain.

Comment: Is the `BallCount` multiple of 5 or `x` factor always ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there is some easier way like lists for this, because when I type
>   getters and setters for this, code goes really huge ?

Not really, you don't need huge list of `getter` methods for this.
You can use `enum` type for your `BallCounts` as shown below with a single `get` method as shown below:

```
public enum BallCounts {

        LEVEL1(5), LEVEL2(10);//add other levels

        private int level;

        private BallCounts(int count) {
            this.level = level;
        }

        //Single getter method
        public int getBallCountLevel() {
            return level;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Enum was the best thing to go for this one. I made an array of enums and accessed them using constructor :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do in this way:

```
private final int [] levelBallCounts = {5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60};

public int getLevelBallCountAtPos(int pos){
    return levelBallCounts[pos-1];
}
```

or simply (without using `levelBallCounts` array):

```
public int getLevelBallCountAtPos(int pos){
    return pos*5;
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(getLevelBallCountAtPos(1)); //returns 5
System.out.println(getLevelBallCountAtPos(4)); //returns 20
System.out.println(getLevelBallCountAtPos(12)); //returns 60
```

Comment: Please OP, Go with this answer. Was gonna type this but he beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Even putting in a List can be nice, it depends on what you prefer or need.

Declaration:

```
private static final List<Integer> levelBallCounts;
static {
   levelBallCounts = new ArrayList<>();
   levelBallCounts.add(5);
   levelBallCounts.add(10);
   [...]
}
[...]
```

Call with:

```
levelBallCounts.get(...)
```